# Calling SSIS Package from command line

Tags: windows, ssis, cmd

I have an Import SSIS Package with Date Filters and few other Export Packages for Excel as output.

I need to give this setup ( i.e) Sequence of Package Execution to my Business Team. Only one person needs this application.

I wonder to finish this assignment on the command line or is there any easiest way to finish this Simple SSIS Package Execution with Date Parameters at the earliest.

Comment: So you've created the package? You have a DTSX file? You can run this in DOS using DTEXEC.EXE but you must have SSIS installed. This is usually not an option for business users. Another option is to run the package in a a SQL Agent job but again this requires elevated security setup for the user and is non trivial. Please indicate the exact version of SSIS as there are more execution options.

Comment: Yeah you are right about it. Is it possible to schedule Monthly data extraction in SQL AGent. Like Every Month on day 1, Import the previous month data.

Comment: Yes. Why don't you take a look at SQL Agent and try it and get back if you have problems.

Answer (score 1):

You can run an SSIS package from the command line using DTEXEC.EXE utility.

Here's a link to documentation: [DTExec Utility](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810(v=sql.105).aspx)